# DFS Replication not "snappy" enough (Missing files)

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, dfs-r, file-replication-services

I have two Domain Controllers.

DC01 usually contains everything and is doing great (AFAIK), however DC02 is constantly "missing" files that are clearly visible on DC01 and should have been replicated over.

The following errors can for an example be found in Event Viewer.

*Example:*

> The DFS Replication service has been repeatedly prevented from
>   replicating a file due to consistent sharing violations encountered on
>   the file. The service failed to stage a file for replication due to a
>   sharing violation.
>
> Additional Information:  File Path:
>   E:\fs\dep\pu\documents\meetings\110325.ppt  Replicated Folder Root:
>   e:\fs File ID: {FC3F83F7-ACB7-47C6-83D6-25A7029A73DB}-v1183507 
>   Replicated Folder Name: FS  Replicated Folder ID:
>   C9A1D84D-2C0D-49E9-B79B-2A002D46A1E0  Replication Group Name:
>   brandos.local\brandos\fs  Replication Group ID:
>   A1BAE4C9-E711-48C1-937A-584B0FB22528  Member ID:
>   A991041C-240D-4654-9DA2-D2E60605DD10

Any idea why files are missing?

Answer (score 6):

It's amazing how the answer is sometimes staring you right in the face:

> The DFS Replication service has been repeatedly prevented from replicating a file due to consistent sharing violations encountered on the file. The service failed to stage a file for replication due to a sharing violation.
>
> Additional Information: File Path: E:\fs\dep\pu\documents\meetings\110325.ppt Replicated Folder Root: e:\fs File ID: {FC3F83F7-ACB7-47C6-83D6-25A7029A73DB}-v1183507 Replicated Folder Name: FS Replicated Folder ID: C9A1D84D-2C0D-49E9-B79B-2A002D46A1E0 Replication Group Name: brandos.local\brandos\fs Replication Group ID: A1BAE4C9-E711-48C1-937A-584B0FB22528 Member ID: A991041C-240D-4654-9DA2-D2E60605DD10

The file 110325.ppt has been opened with an exclusive WRITE lock. DFSR can't replicate a file if it's locked. Investigate the cause of the lock and release it and you'll fix the issue. This is not a bug or problem in DFSR, this is the way it should operate. You wouldn't want DFSR to try and replicate a file that's locked for editing, would you?

**From Microsoft:** DFSR will not replicate a file in or out if its local copy has an exclusive lock.

Answer (score -1):

While both AD replication and DFS use FRS as the transport method, they have absolutely nothing to do with one another.

DFS is a complex topic, and problems will be reported in the event logs on both the origin server and any slaves.
You could have a too small staging area, or a slow disk for the slave, or...

Investigate!

Comment: You're a little mixed up. FRS and DFS-R are two different technologies. DFS does not use FSR for anything. In fact, a 2008R2 DFL domain **will** use DFS instead of FRS for sysvol replication.

Comment: In 2008, maybe - I have no experience with that.
In 2003, DFS most certainly uses FRS for replication.
While the OP was tagged, he did not mention any specific OS version(s).

Comment: The question was about 2008 R2.